# Handling the hotfix branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

Our current branching strategy is using three branches: `default`, `release`, `hotfix`.

`hotfix` is branched off release and then, following QA/testing, merged back into `release`, then into `default`.

When the next release is completed and another hotfix needs to be created, should we update the `hotfix` branch with the latest code or just `force` create a new `hotfix` branch from the latest release branch?

My instinct is to recreate the branch to be more explicit in when and why the branch was recreated. However, I'm not sure if there are any drawbacks to recreating the branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could **give each release/hotfix branch its own name**, e.g. `v1.0.0` and `v1.0.0-hotfix`.  At the time of the next release, you could close the old release/hotfix branches.

You could also **create hotfix-specific branches on an as-needed basis**.  When you identify a new hotfix, give it a name and/or identifier, create a branch for it (e.g. `hotfix-v1.0.0-001`) and make the hotfix.  Once it is accepted, merge it into `release` and close it.

Or, if you want to keep your current `release`/`hotfix` naming scheme, **when you release a new product, merge default into release then release into hotfix**.  Because you've been merging them down into default, you shouldn't get any merge conflicts.  If you do, you know to always take the side from default.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks (performance wise, in the long run) to creating a new branch with the same name `hotfix` everytime we need to issue a hotfix? Or is maintaing a single `hotfix` branch an uncommon branching strategy?

Comment: @Omar I'm not sure about the performance drawbacks of one approach versus another.  The biggest distinction between them is the number of branches you end up with over time.  I don't think maintaining a single `release` branch or `hotfix` branch is uncommon.  From an agile perspective, it makes sense to to do it that way.

Comment: Potential advantage: having one consistent branch name for one consistent concept makes it easier to integrate into a continuous integration system.

Comment: On a related note, If you're using Git Flow in SourceTree, it only allows you to make one hotfix branch at a time no matter the branch name.